how to make full static like the red part make it like the blue marked part
how to make full static like the red part make it like the blue marked part. 

Have you use Mega Menu extension into system?

You can do this with css.
Set width of the ul class="level0" to the width of the parent.
in my case i set the width to 1250px in desktop view.
Or search for "Mega Menu" module but they aren't free


it works but the menu still going down, i try the position (relative, absolute etc) but still the same.
